# Replace first element in nested list with dictionary key value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

#### Goal

Create a new list with the first element of each nested list replaced with the corresponding value from the dictionary. Assume all objects will be keys present in dictionary.

```
d = {'A': 'Orange',
 'B': 'Apples',
 'C': 'Bananas'}


l = [['A', 'Foo', 'Bar'],
     ['A', 'Bar', 'Foo'],
     ['B', 'Frog', 'Mouse'],
     ['C', 'Owl', 'Ant'],
     ['C', 'Foo', 'Bar']]

Goal:
[['Orange', 'Foo', 'Bar'],
['Orange', 'Bar', 'Foo'],
['Apples', 'Frog', 'Mouse'],
['Bananas', 'Owl', 'Ant'],
['Bananas', 'Foo', 'Bar']]
```

#### What I Did

```
repl = [d[x[0] for x in l]

for i in range(len(l)):
   l[i][0] = repl[i]
```

Looking to receive feedback and improvements to the way that I went about solving this task. My solution definitely operates under the assumption that the ordering of the nested list will not change, but I would like to get feedback from others and bolster the solution for edge-cases.

Comment: your first line has a syntax error

Comment: and if you want a review of working code you should go to http://codereview.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You are making two loops when one will suffice. Also, unless you really need the index, you should avoid the `for...range(len(l))` pattern in favor of just looping over the elements: `for sub_list in l: sub_list[0] = d[sub_list[0]]`

Comment: `[[d[x[0]]] + x[1:] for x in l]`

Comment: The url for code review is a stackexchange not stackoverflow: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
In [28]: d = {'A': 'Orange',
    ...:      'B': 'Apples',
    ...:      'C': 'Bananas'}
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: l = [['A', 'Foo', 'Bar'],
    ...:      ['A', 'Bar', 'Foo'],
    ...:      ['B', 'Frog', 'Mouse'],
    ...:      ['C', 'Owl', 'Ant'],
    ...:      ['C', 'Foo', 'Bar']]

In [31]: for item in l:
    ...:     item[0] = d[item[0]]
```

The benefit is that the code accomplishes the work in a single loop over the input data.

Python `for` loops do not require that you calculate the length, thus there is no reason for you to calculate the `range(len)` value.

Similarly, since the `for` loop automatically references each item in the data using the target variable (here I am calling it `item`) then we can reference any element in the item (i.e. using `item[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your original code, all you need to do is add an extra `]` to the first line.

```
repl = [d[x[0]] for x in l]

for i in range(len(l)):
   l[i][0] = repl[i]
```